# SQL Update with ColdFusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am trying to update a database with a form in ColdFusion. I think that my form is correct, but not working.Now I don't see an error in there `update_action.cfm` page, but is there?

Below is the main form

```
<cfquery name="GetRecordtoUpdate" datasource="elephant_shack">
    SELECT *
    FROM Richard
    WHERE record_id = #URL.record_id#
</cfquery>


<table>
    <cfoutput query= "GetRecordtoUpdate">
        <form action="update_action.cfm" method="Post">
               <tr>
                <td width="93">record id:</td> 
                <td width="286"><input name="record_id" type="text" value="#record_id#" size="25"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="93">Item:</td> 
                <td width="286"><input name="item" type="text" value="#item#" size="25"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Stock:</td>
                <td><input name="stock" type="text" value="#stock#" size="12"></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Par:</td>
                <td><input name="par" type="text" value="#par#" size="12"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Order:</td>
                <td><input name="order" type="text" value="#order#" size="50"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="Submit" value="Update Information"></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
</table>
    </cfoutput>
```

Here is the update_action page

```
   <!--- update form--->
   <h2>Vendor updated</h2>          
    <p class="note">You have updated the following information in the in the Vendor Richard's database for:.</p>
   <!--- Insert record --->
<cfquery datasource="elephant_shack">
    INSERT INTO Richard(Item,Stock,Par,Order)

    VALUES('#FORM.item#','#FORM.stock#','#FORM.par#','#FORM.order#')
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of the SELECT

Comment: the * means I am selecting everything

Comment: OT: Please use cfqueryparam. This code is wide open to all kinds of bad things.

Comment: I know what * means, thanks. :-/

Comment: @James I am going off CFWACK Book, and no cfqueryparam, but I am looking online now. It's for the WHERE clause, right? Any chance of an example?

Comment: `<cfqueryparam` tags are used in queries where we are going to use users inputs like `'#FORM.order#', '#FORM.item#', etc`. This is primarily for preventing [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: eg. The query will looks something like [this](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=b1a5e730-fc5b-4d28-b299-098f8d1a5c39/c1dff753-e2b3-4944-9a56-3c9c7bc84489/6cd7b2a6-4926-4d39-9688-62a4a84acf59.cfm). You can specify the type of value you are trying to pass to the query. Find more info from [here](https://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam).

Comment: How are you determining it is not working, if you are not getting an error? Also, you say you are trying to UPDATE a record, but the code shows an INSERT.  Is that correct code?

Comment: What is the workflow here? Do you do a `SELECT` to get the data and then an `INSERT` to essentially version a row? If not, then you want an `UPDATE` instead. Regardless, both of these queries are wide open to SQL Injection and a bunch of other nasty things. The WACK is a good book, but it is pretty dated at this point. Take a look at http://www.learncfinaweek.com/ or some of the other resources like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment rather than answer to the original question  what ` is for

**Reason 1**

`<cfqueryparam>` is for all data, but it is especially from data from `url` or `form`

Consider the following

```
<cfquery datasource="elephant_shack">
    INSERT INTO Richard(Item,Stock,Par,Order)

    VALUES('#FORM.item#','#FORM.stock#','#FORM.par#','#FORM.order#')
</cfquery>
```

If someone submits data that looks like

```
'); TRUNCATE Richard SELECT '
```

Then everything is gone. Do a Google search on "Little Bobby Tables"

**Reason 2**

But there is another reason to use `cfqueryparam`. Database make plans on how to process the data. If you do this

```
<cfquery datasource="elephant_shack">
    INSERT INTO Richard(Item,Stock,Par,Order)

    VALUES('#FORM.item#','#FORM.stock#','#FORM.par#','#FORM.order#')
</cfquery>
```

A new plan has to be made for every insert. Or more accurately, plans never get reused. Now when you use `cfqueryparam`, ColdFusion is actually creating something like this.

```
<cfquery datasource="elephant_shack">
    DECLARE @item  varchar(2000) = '#EscapeSQL(form.item)#'
    DECLARE @stock varchar(2000) = '#EscapeSQL(form.item)#'
    DECLARE @par   varchar(2000) = '#EscapeSQL(form.item)#'
    DECLARE @order varchar(2000) = '#EscapeSQL(form.item)#'


    INSERT INTO Richard(Item,Stock,Par,Order)
    VALUES(@item, @stock, @par, @order)
</cfquery>
```

Now the data is escaped before it even comes it. it is forced to match an SQL data type very early. And the INSERT plan can be used over and over again, because it will stay the same for every insert.

Disclaimer, I don't know what the default varchar length is. Nor do I know what the internal EscapeSQL function is really called

Examples: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2007/02/18/Simple-guide-to-switching-to-CFQUERYPARAM

Comment: In SQL Server, default length of a `varchar` depends on the context. Sometimes it's 30, sometimes it's 1, sometimes it's whatever it wants to be. And the best part is that sometimes it will cause silent truncation. Those are always fun. I'm not sure how MySQL handles it differently, but I do believe no varchar length can heavily impact resource usage on the MySQL server.

Comment: There are functions for escaping single quotes and other things, but the `cfqueryparam` will do a lot of that. Depending on what type of data OP is working with, a function to sanitize the input before sending it to the query in a `cfqueryparam` would be good.